# print a text between 2 keywords

Tags: python, html

I am working with html files. I want to extract the text which comes before the first Item 2 and after the Item 1a (thanks for helping part). First I delete the text that comes after the second Item 2.

```
text= """"""<this is an example this is Item&nbsp;2. A href="#106">Item&nbsp;1a. thanks for helping <B>Item&nbsp;2. Properties</B> this is an example this is Item&nbsp;2.stachoverflow"""

>>> a=re.search ('(?<=<B>)Item&nbsp;2\.',text)
>>> b = a.span()
>>> newText= text[:b[1]]
>>> c=newText.rfind("1a")
>>> (newText[c[1]:])

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

how can I print the text which comes after c ?

Answer (score 0):

If your just trying to print the output, you are trying to access c as an array - it is an index. So to print c, it would just be (newText[c:]).

However, your search isn't correct either, as you need newText= text[:b[0]], not 1.